# List with full justification

Tags: html, list, justify

I'm trying to make a simple list in html where the text in the list items are fully justified.

This is the list I would like to full justify:

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Attention Restoration Theory</strong></p>

<ol>
    <li>Faszination: Die Natur weckt Aufmerksamkeit, die nicht anstrengt, sondern regeneriert.</li>
    <li>Weg sein: Die Natur ermöglicht einen Abstand zum Alltag.</li>
    <li>Ausdehnung: Die Natur ermöglicht das Gefühl, sich mit dieser verbunden zu fühlen.</li>
    <li>Kompatibilität: Die Natur bietet einer Person die Möglichkeit, zu tun, was ihren Bedürfnissen entspricht.</li>
</ol>
```

How do I justify the above list?

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Attention Restoration Theory</strong></p>

<ol style="max-width: max-content; text-align-last: justify;">
    <li>Faszination: Die Natur weckt Aufmerksamkeit, die nicht anstrengt, sondern regeneriert.</li>
    <li>Weg sein: Die Natur ermöglicht einen Abstand zum Alltag.</li>
    <li>Ausdehnung: Die Natur ermöglicht das Gefühl, sich mit dieser verbunden zu fühlen.</li>
    <li>Kompatibilität: Die Natur bietet einer Person die Möglichkeit, zu tun, was ihren Bedürfnissen entspricht.</li>
</ol>
```